# Javascript - Generate new color on every mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Edit** :  The only issue I had was the lack of jQuery

---

My [code](https://jsfiddle.net/Microsmsm/sdrxaay0/2/) Should generate a new color on every mouseover but it don't work can you tell me please where the problem ?

```js
var number;
var newColor;
setInterval(function() {
  number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1);
  newColor = "#" + number;
}, 1000);
$("#myBtn").mouseover(function() {
  $("#myDiv").css("background-color", newColor);
});
```

```css
div {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myBtn">Hover Here To Change Color</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: in the snippet above, $ is not defined ... you've loaded jQuery?

Comment: Can you explain what does not work and what is the desired behavior

Comment: this wont change the colour every second whilst the mouse is over the button, if that's what you intended - mouseover is triggered when the mouse enters an element, doesn't trigger again until you leave and enter the element again

Comment: @Rajesh this should change the div backgound color on every mouseover  but it doesn't work

Comment: @JaromandaX yes I understand

Comment: You were right @JaromandaX i was forgetting jQuery :D !

Comment: who made negative vote :D !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only issue I had was the lack of jQuery

Answer (score 1):

This code will change the colour every second whilst the mouse is over the button - if that was not your intention, then the only issue you had was the lack of jQuery

```js
var isOver = false; // only required if colour should change continuously
var newColor;
setInterval(function() {
  var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1);
  newColor = "#" + number;
  // next 3 lines only required if colour should change continuously
  if(isOver) {
    $("#myDiv").css("background-color", newColor);
  }
}, 1000);
$("#myBtn").mouseover(function() {
  isOver = true; // only required if colour should change continuously
  $("#myDiv").css("background-color", newColor);
});
// next 3 lines only required if colour should change continuously
$("#myBtn").mouseout(function() {
  isOver = false;
});
```

```css
div {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myBtn">Hover Here To Change Color</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: to be honest, you didn't need an answer unless you wanted continuous changes while the mouse is over the button

Comment: no no your answer was very helpful to me. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

This one will change color on every `mouseover`.

I took out the `setInterval` as I can't see why you need that...?

```js
$("#myBtn").mouseover(function() {
  $("#myDiv").css("background-color", "#" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1));
});
```

```css
div {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myBtn">Hover Here To Change Color</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: I was missing jQuery in the snippet

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your code with below code

```js
var number;
var newColor;

$("#myBtn").mouseover(function() {
  number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1);
  newColor = "#" + number;
  $("#myDiv").css("background-color", newColor);
});
```

```css
div {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myBtn">Hover Here To Change Color</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On codepen it works for me , if you want to get a new color on mouse over and not mouseout you should set the mouseout to the same color.